# Displaying buffer around feature using population values in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, population

I am working on a project that is about park accessibility.

I wanted to display a buffer from a park that shows potentially 3 acres/3000 population.  I am using Census tract data and I have a shape of all the parks.

I was able to create a quarter mile buffer and then extract the population data from the shape, but I am asking **how do we show how far the reach of a park’s service is for 3000 people**?

I am a little familiar with spatial network analyst, but I am not using any streets, I am just relying on the population value in the tracts.

Any suggestions of what I can do?

Comment: Kind of unclear what you're asking. Given a park, you want to pull out the [census tracts containing a total of 3000 people] that are closest to that park, from a network perspective?

Comment: It would help if you could draw a picture. Do you want to know the parks of 3 arces or more then how far out to go to reach 3k population or is it 1 acre to 1000 population? Census tract data will not give you the information you are after as individual households' population isn't recorded - you will have to approximate using cadastre.